# Window keyup event - can you listen to keyup any time a page is active?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, keyup

I am trying to write something simple using vanilla js to fire a function at the time when say, a user hits the enter key. I have found some code below, but I wasn't sure how to make it work, since the function has no name.

```
function (event) {
  if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Wooohoo");
  }
};
```

I saw some other solutions by changing the body tag, but I have no control over as I am writing this script for a Sharepoint page. I would think that there has to be some simple way to capture the enter key without anything selected necessarily, but I am not finding much information on it. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set that function to the document's `onkeyup` event, like this:

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
  if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Wooohoo");
  }
};
```

That way that function will trigger any time a `keyup` event fires in the page.